# Strangeness and G-parity of glueballs

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

I know that glueballs are virtual particles predicted by QCD and that they form a color singlet. I am stucked in the problem, which seems to be a easy one, of finding the strangennes and G-parity of such a particle. I don't know, or I don't remember, how to find the quantum number S (strangeness) without any previous information about charge - or hypercharge. I know that the simplest glueball has positive parity, zero angular momentum and even under charge conjugation. It means that its G-parity is positive, because the angular momentum is zero and C-parity is positive - it was given. What is troubling me is the strangeness. I believe it has to be zero, but I can't show that.

Answer (score 1):

[glue ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball)

> In particle physics, a glueball (also gluonium, gluon-ball) is a hypothetical composite particle.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball) It consists solely of gluon particles, without valence quarks.

Strangeness is a conserved quantum number except in weak decays. A glue ball consists of gluons which may loop to particle antiparticle pairs which carry zero strangeness, beauty, charm  quantum numbers , as they can only be created by strong interactions in such pairs.